# MadelineProto requires the libtgvoip extension to run

Tags: php, telegram, voip

I follow the process to install madeline and it is working fine to join groups and send messages, but when I try to make a call using the examples provided, I get the following error:

```
MadelineProto requires the libtgvoip extension to run. Follow the instructions @ https://voip.madelineproto.xyz to install it.
Error: Call to undefined method danog\MadelineProto\Coroutine::play() in /var/www/html/madeline_cli_pepe/test.php:34 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: {closure}() #1
```

I tried from different Ubuntu version but I get the same resut. Any idea what could be the root cuase?
thank you.

Comment: The message says you don't have `php-libtgvoip` extension, have you installed and enable it?

Comment: "_Follow the instructions @ https://voip.madelineproto.xyz to install it._" Did that not work?

Comment: I follow the instructions available @ voip.madelineproto.xyz to install the library but there is nothing mention to enable it. Maybe that is the problem...  How can I check if the library is enabled?